# How to copy files from windows to linux using shell script?

Tags: linux, windows, file, shell, move

I have jenkins in my local machine. I created one zip file through jenkins. 
After creating Zip file, how can i move file from windows to linux through automation? If anyone have idea please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/),[smb](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-samba-connect-share.html) or [sshd](http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=download)